# c shell while loop stack not that deep

Tags: while-loop, stack, csh

I am new to c shell. I have a problem using the while loop, the error message is "directory stack not deep". Here is my while loop.

```
set i = 1
while ($i < =10)
    echo $i
end
```

**EDIT:**

I solve the problem by removing the space between '<' and '='.

```
set i = 1
while ($i <=10)
    echo $i
end
```

Comment: try without a space (`<=` not `< =`)

Comment: thank you @John3136 for debuggung my stupid mistake.

Comment: please close or delete your question as this won't really help anyone in the future. Good luck.

Comment: @shelter, No question...however small, is useless. I had a similar error with same msg...but different context. I got "directory not that deep" in following bash command line : 'env ERROR_COUNTRY=1 =10 ls '.  Solution is to remove the spurious "=10"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP answered his own question: the less-than-or-equal operator is spelled `<=`, not `< =`.